# QTP for load test?

Tags: load-testing, qtp, performance-testing, loadrunner

I'm have some question about QTP 11, QTP 11 can be use loadtesting for performance test similar loadruner in Performance Center ? or QTP for functional test only?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK generally QTP is not used for load testing, though it is possible to measure transaction time for a business scenario using Start and End transaction.You can execute QTP scripts which would in-turn be a part of the load testing.But to go deep into load testing, you need to use other load testing tools like HP LoadRunner. It is obvious as both tools, QTP & LoadRunner, are from HP(this also signifies,according to HP for load testing you should use different testing tool) both tool can be use together for load testing,
[Here](http://www.loadrunnertnt.com/concepts/using-qtp-with-loadrunner-for-load-testing/) is the link.

Answer (score 2):

QTP is used as a Graphical Virtual User in a LoadRunner model.   This requires a single OS instance per virtual user.    GUI Virtual users were the first virtual user type for LoadRunner in version 1, which ran multiple versions of XRunner.   Up until version 4, XRunner was the GUI VirtuaL User of Choice.   From Versions 4 to 6, Graphical Virtual Users were available on both UNIX and Windows Systems, using XRunner on UNIX and WinRunner on Windows.    By The time of version 3 API versions of the virtual users had replaced GUI Virtual Users for Primary Load.

From Version 8 forward QuickTest Profession was available as a Graphical Virtual user type.   With Version 11 the default GUI Virtual user type is QTP, WinRunner is no longer supported.

So yes, the two can be integrated.  There is a long history of using the functional automated testing tools within the Mercury/HP family with the performance testing tools.

The use of graphical performance testing tools fell out of favor for a while during the era of the thin web client.   As web clients have gotten thicker, with the ability to run Javascript, C# and other technologies, the need to measure the difference between API level and GUI level has come back into vogue.   In addition to the traditional GUI Virtual user, HP also offers TruClient.   TruClient's main advantage is that you can run multiple TruClient virtual users per OS instance, in contrast to the GUI Virtual user where you can execute only a single virtual user per OS instance (on Microsoft Windows).

Talk to your VAR.   GUI Virtual Users run about 1k per virtual user in bundles of five or better.   It is not anticipated that you will ever run a full performance test using all graphical virtual users.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course write a script in QTP for say logging into a website and run that script via loadrunner.

But firstly, the time will not be exact as QTP will add its own time (for execution) to the response time.

Secondly you will be able to simulate only one user per machine, while as Load runner simulates hundreds of users at a time.

Answer (score -1):

No. UFT alone cannot perform load test.All you can do is measure transaction time that's all. The purpose of UFT tool is to automate GUI and API testing. For Load test, you need to use Load Runner.

Comment: See concept, "GUI Virtual User..."  Supported since the very first version of LoadRunner

Answer (score -1):

UFT is basically for functional testing, said that you can do basic performance testing using UFT. Transaction Times and Page Loads. You can get the time take to complete any action, or time taken to load pages/images.

Comment: See GUI Virtual User.  This has been available in every version of LoadRunner delivered to the market